# Why did opening a large text file hang my entire system, not the editor?

Tags: kde, freeze, kde-neon

Recently, I made the mistake of opening a large-ish text file (~100MB) in Kedit. This made my system entirely unresponsive and I had to reboot it using the REISUB method.

I was wondering why this made the entire system hang, rather than just the application (Kedit), and how to prevent it from happening in the future?

My CPU is an i5-7600k, I have 8GB of RAM and am running off a 3TB HDD.

Answer (score 0):

100MB isn't that large, I have read gigabyte-sized log files.

But if the file is made of lots of tiny lines, and if the editor loads them into somewhat larger buffers, this will make the RAM footprint of the result much larger. I don't know `kedit` but `kate`, for instance, loads a ~100MB file (10M 10-bytes lines) in 1.3G of RAM, so I assume it uses 128-byte buffers.

And once you get short on RAM the whole system swaps and this impacts all apps.

But to confirm this answer use `ksysguard` and check the total RAM/Swap usage and the memory usage of your editor.